# Lookup tables: store in database, code or memory?

Tags: caching, lookup, lookup-tables

I can think of three ways to deal with lookup tables:

1. Store them in the database (which enforces referential integrity)
2. Store them in the code (which helps speed)
3. Store them in a db but cache them with redis or memcached.

What is your typically method when scalability is a requirement?

I've not been able to find an answer that balances reliability with scalability.